# Error: Class 'PHPUnit_Util_ErrorHandler' not found

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, composer-php

this is the relevant composer.jpon config.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "twig/twig": "^2.0",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.11.3",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.5",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.7",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "dev-master",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "^3.3",
    "components/jquery": "^2.1",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.3",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3",
    "phpunit/dbunit": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
},
```

When i execute `php phpunit` the following appears:

Time: 1.01 seconds, Memory: 20.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) UserBundle\Tests\Unit\ScaleUserServiceTest::testIsUsersEmpty
Error: Class 'PHPUnit_Util_ErrorHandler' not found

Can someone help me what to do?

Thanks in advance,
Max

Answer (score 1):

You are installing PHPUnit 6. That version does not have `PHPUnit_Util_ErrorHandler` anymore.

Information on migrating to PHPUnit 6 can be found [here](https://thephp.cc/news/2017/02/migrating-to-phpunit-6), the complete list of changes in PHPUnit 6 is available [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/6.0/ChangeLog-6.0.md).

Comment: I expected that my problem came from an "too-new" package, but could not find out which it was. Thanks Sebastian.

Now i have changed under require: phpunit/phpunit to ^5.0 and under require-dev phpunit/dbunit to ^2.0

But now i have another problem, since my test base on PHPUnit\DbUnit\TestCase

What do you recomment for me now?

Comment: Or is there another, better way, to make my tests work? Maybe even with PHPUnit6?

Comment: My Stacktrace shows me, that the error comes from the line that contains:
file_get_contents('testfile.txt');

Nothing more

Comment: i think i got my system workling by updating symfony/phpunit-bridge to 3.2.4